# Scilab / Scicos installation problems

Tags: installation, scilab

I have an issue regarding the installtion of scilab 64 bit.

Currently I am using the 32 bit versions of (6.1.1) without any problems.
My newest project (xcos electrical circuit) is quite big. A scilab error "out of memory" pops up.
I tried to fix the problem by using the 64 bit versions of scilab.
Folloing error occurs while running of any xcos model (demos included)

-------Modelica translator error message:----
"c_pass1: build the modelica meta-block failed"

"xcos_simulate: Error during block parameters update."

Scilab and compiler installation with following procedure

1. installation Scilab
2. installation of the gcc compiler (mingw package atoms)
3. restart pc
4. atomsInstall('mingw')
5. restart scilab
6. loading of the libary (happen automatically)

32 bit versions works perfect
64 bit version doesnt work

I didn't change anything in the environment variables
The problem occurs on both of my pc (windows 10 pro, newly setup)

I hope someone can help me

Kind regarads
Niki

Comment: I don't think that using the 64 bits version of Scilab will solve the memory problem. However, I have some questions: did you install the correct version (64 bits) version of Equation Solution GCC package ? Did you make any test showing that the compiler works (I suggest running the first example  of the help page of `ilib_build`) ?

Comment: Hi Stephane, the only thing next to scilab I have installed is https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/10.3.0/files/gcc-10.3.0-64.exe.. I have tested some examples and they don't work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the output (at scilab prompt) of `haveacompiler` ? Same question for `getenv("EQ_LIBRARY_PATH")`

Comment: --> haveacompiler()
 ans  =

  T

Comment: getenv("EQ_LIBRARY_PATH") "C:\Users\Dell-Laptop\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib"

Comment: As a last resort, I suggest the following (force rebuild of compatibility Scilab libraries): `cd SCIHOME; rmdir("mingwlib_x64","s")`, then restart Scilab. There should be a lengthy recompile time at startup. Then try again the `ilib_build` example.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean ? Did the libraries rebuild without error ?

Comment: yes, without error! The problem is the same, "modelica translator error message"

Comment: You didn't tell if the ilib_build example works, does it ?

Comment: No it doesnt.    "compilation terminated."                                                                                 
  "make: *** [Makelib:114: sci_fun1.o] Error 1"

Comment: Can you try again but launch Scilab with adminstrator rights ?

Comment: I did, it didn't work.

Comment: Do both 32 bits and 64 bits versions of Scilab are installed on the computer where you are doing the tests ?

Comment: not at the same time! currently it is only the 64 bits version!

Comment: You should test that gcc works on the Windows command line, with a simple source like `#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("hello world\n");}`